# MonoDroid: Fragments - Detail Fragment

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, fragment

In the **Mono for Android** documentation example project "**HoneycombFragments**" in the **TitlesFragment** this line appears in the **OnActivityCreated**.

```
        var detailsFrame = Activity.FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.details);
        _isDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible;
```

At this stage in the lifecycle, where is the Detail View being created as it's not referred to in the Layout xml nor is it in the code at this stage (detail view is added in code at a later stage). It's magically made it seems as the Detail View constructor is not being called as of yet either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the editor. When there are 2 Layouts with the same name, double clicking one, then the other gives you the same file. Because of this I could not see the Detail View that was in fact added to the XML in the second xml.

[image]